# Controlling order of execution in dplyr filter statements

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to control the order that a `dplyr::filter` command executes without breaking it into separate filter statements? For example, given the following data frame, and a goal of keeping only rows for groups that participated at least once in 2017:

```
library(dplyr)

## data
dat <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
           fy = c(2017, 2017, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2018),
           val = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)) %>% 
  group_by(grp)
```

I noticed that this syntax returns an incorrect result set as it returns rows from group b:

```
dat %>% 
  filter(fy <= 2017 & sum(val) >= 1)
```

While the syntax below returns the correct result set, however it requires two separate filter statements where the year filter is explicitly executed before the sum function:

```
## correctly only returns rows from group a
dat %>% 
  filter(fy <= 2017) %>% 
  filter(sum(val) >= 1)
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case and whether there is a way to avoid it without separate filter statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the different filter statements to figure out what is going on:

```
dat %>% 
  filter(fy <= 2017 & sum(val) >= 1)
```

The statement above filters all rows where `fy <= 2017` and where the `sum` of the column `val` *for each group in* `dat` is equal to 1 or larger.

`sum(val) >= 1` gives you one output: `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each group (`dat` is grouped by `grp`). This vector of length one (for each group) is recycled to the number of rows of each group in `dat`, because this is the tidyverse standard behavior. When we look at each group in `grp` we can see that `sum(val)` is `2` for `grp` `a` and `1` for group `b`. This is not your expected output.

Let's look at the next statement:

```
dat %>% 
  filter(fy <= 2017) %>% 
  filter(sum(val) >= 1)
```

Here we first filter all rows where `fy <= 2017`. Now `sum(val)` is `1` for group `a` and `0` for group `b`. Adding another filter expression with `sum(val) >= 1` now results in your expected output.

Another option is to group by `grp` and `fy` and then use one filter statement: `fy <= 2017 & sum(val) >= 1)`. This filter all rows where `fy <= 2017` AND all rows which belong to combinations of `grp` and `fy` where `sum(val) <= 1`.

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(grp, fy) %>%
  filter(fy <= 2017 & sum(val) >= 1)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   grp, fy [1]
#>   grp      fy   val
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a      2017     0
#> 2 a      2017     1
```

Answer (score 1):

All references are to the original values of the variables coming into the filter statement but you can do this although using separate filter statements seems simpler in this case.

```
out1 <- dat %>% filter(fy <= 2017 & sum(val[fy <= 2017]) >= 1)
out2 <- dat %>% filter(fy <= 2017) %>% filter(sum(val) >= 1)
identical(out1, out2)
## [1] TRUE
```